# Convert from exponential notation to non-exponential notation

Tags: c#

I have tried:

```
MessageBox.Show(System.Numerics.BigInteger.Parse("7.56e+011",
          NumberStyles.Float,
          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

But it continues to show 7.56e+011

Comment: This code won't even compile. Add `ToString()` at the end and you'll get `756000000000` value in `num`

Comment: @Lloyd `BigInteger.Parse("7.56e+011", NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString()` returns `756000000000`

Comment: @IlyaIvanov Adding ToString() gives the same output

Comment: @kr13 show the **full, compiling** example, with code that reads input and produces outputs

Comment: @IlyaIvanov This is all I have. I am reading the value from a text file and need to display it e.g with a MessageBox

Comment: You wrote `I have tried:`, how can you try a code, which doesn't even compile?

Comment: @IlyaIvanov It appears to be compiling for others too

Comment: @IlyaIvanov I apologize. You were right. I had made a quick edit which indeed does not compile. I have changed that now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking to format the number.  You can use [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) to do so

```
string.Format("{0:F}",System.Numerics.BigInteger.Parse("7.56e+011",
          NumberStyles.Float,
          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```

Running the following code

[image: Code in VS2012]

Gives you the following MessageBox

[image: MessageBox with string]

you can specify no decimal points by changing it to `{0:F0}` for the format.

Comment: @kr13 please look at my edits.  This shows it working with the MessageBox that you say you need it to display in

Answer (score 0):

```
    decimal dec = decimal.Parse("7.7583877127496407E-6", 
    System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any);
    Console.WriteLine(dec);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
BigInteger num = System.Numerics.BigInteger.Parse("7.56e+011",
      NumberStyles.Float,
      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

String text = num.ToString("F5"); // New format string, here with 5 digits.
```

Your solution does an implicit conversion from BigInteger back to string again, which uses the scientific notation if the exponent is large.

Comment: It will not compile. "Cannot convert from BigInteger  to string"

Comment: ??? Works perfectly for me. I can't see where this would try to do an implicity cast.